# Reference counted object is used after being it is released

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, ios4

I am getting memory warning as "Reference counted object is used after being it is released"

For this i have tried autorelease also. but no use.

below is the code which gives my warning.what is the issue. pls let me know

```
UICustomSwitch *switchView = [[UICustomSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                [switchView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180,5,260,30)];
                [switchView setOn:YES];
                mySearchType = 1;
                [[switchView rightLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:16.0f]];
                [[switchView leftLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:16.0f]];
                [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:switchView];
```

Comment: Why did you init your switchView twice?

Comment: i agree with lu yuan, you could have just init'ed it with the frame first time instead of cgrectzero. btw i don't think the code you pasted shows the complete picture - from the code, switchview doesnt seem to be being accessed out of context, so the suspect is the cell - it may have already been released. can you post the whole method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the following code

```
UICustomSwitch *switchView = [[UICustomSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                [switchView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180,5,260,30)];
```

into

```
UICustomSwitch *switchView = [[UICustomSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180,5,260,30)];
```